# Save and retrive Images in BLOB field in oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle

How can I save and retrieve images in Blob field in Oracle using C#? 
Is it a good choice to use database to store image?

Comment: What tool are you using to store and retrieve images?  Do you want to load images from a client file system using SQL*Loader?  Insert them via Java?  Do you have an APEX app where you want to upload images?  Something else?

Comment: I am using C# to store image. The user can either Browse the image file or capture image using Webcam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using C#, you probably want to start with Microsoft's [Working with Oracle LOBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cydxhzhz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  That has a number of examples of reading and writing LOBs to an Oracle database using the OracleLob class.

As to whether it is a good idea to use the database to store images, as with all things, it depends.  Storing images in the database ensures that images are protected by transactional integrity.  It provides a single place where all the images can reside that will, by definition, be accessible to all the middle tier servers.  It makes it much easier to ensure that all the data is backed up and can be recovered.  It ensures that no one accidentally moves an image without remembering to update the database.

On the other hand, it means that the size of the database may grow substantially and thus be harder to back up.  Presumably, this is just trading database backup size for file system backup size, but this may involve shifting headaches from one group in the organization to another.  It means that you can't manage the images on the file system using file system scripts.  It may make it more difficult to cache the images on the middle tier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of what programming language you are using, but just open your file and write the bytes using Hexadecimal notation.

Here is a example in Java programming language:
http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Oracle-BLOB-SQL-INSERT.html

Edit:You may save the pixels, or compress the image before(in the webcam case). I recommend that you use something like JPEG or PNG before saving the image on the database.